# Match URL's from string but exclude image url's and document url's

Tags: javascript, html

Currently i'm building a function for a messaging system that detects a url from the string and add `anchor` tag to it. But i need to exclude the urls that points to images and documents. The function that i created now detects all the urls and add `anchor` tag to it but it adds anchor tag to images and documents also.

i tried these regex but no desired result

```
/(.[^>"]|[^=]")\b(https?|ftp|file)/gi

/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g
```

```js
    function urlParsing(text) {
      var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
      return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
       return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
      })
    }

    console.log(urlParsing('Hello john https://stackoverflow.com'));

    console.log(urlParsing('Hello john https://picsum.photos/200/300.jpg'));
```

Comment: You said you wanted to `exclude the urls that points to images and documents`. How are you planning on detecting what a URL points to? Unlike local file names, URLs do not necessarily follow any naming patterns. You can not expect all URLs ending in ".jpg" to point to images, just like you can not expect URLs ending in something else to NOT point to an image. The only way I know of to detect the type of resource behind a URL is to fetch its mime type through a direct request.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak i just want to remove png,gif,jpg,pdf and docx

Comment: Our of curiosity, detecting of file type aside, why would you not want to link images and docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a negative lookahead to your regex.  This is the (?!) group, and it means match as long as whatever comes before isn't followed by anything in the lookahead.  Then add a check to test the text against that parser and return from the function if the test fails.

```js
function urlParsing(text) {
      var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/(?!.*\.(jpg|png|gif|pdf|docx))[^\s]+)/g;
      if(!urlRegex.test(text)) {return false};
      return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
       return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
      })
    }

    console.log(urlParsing('Hello john https://stackoverflow.com'));
    console.log(urlParsing('Hello john https://pbs.org'));

    console.log(urlParsing('Hello john https://picsum.photos/200/300.jpg'));
    console.log(urlParsing('Hello john https://picsum.photos/200/300.jpg?arg=x&arg2=y'));
    console.log(urlParsing('Hello john https://picsum.photos/200/300.png'));
    console.log(urlParsing('Hello john https://picsum.photos/200/300.gif'));
    console.log(urlParsing('Hello john https://picsum.photos/200/300.pdf'));
    console.log(urlParsing('Hello john https://picsum.photos/200/300.docx'));
```